# How to find the value of $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{48} \frac{30^k}{k!}$

Tags: summation, exponential-function, poisson-distribution

How do I find the value of the following summation:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{48} \frac{30^k}{k!}$$

I tried using the ratio test to find convergence but maybe that's not the way it should be.

And also I'm not allowed to use graphic/programmable calculator for this.

Comment: why you will use the ration test for a finite sum?

Comment: the result is a big number

Comment: Well I multiply this answer with e^-30 and subtract that from 1, it's just a bigger probability problem and I'm only stuck in the summation part.

Comment: You are essentially computing a value for the CDF of a Poisson distribution. You may exploit the Central Limit Theorem to get an approximation in terms of the error function.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{15101357483145095543048608278289608881317}{1414382685380845484392545457}$ using Wolfram Alpha

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/780456)

Comment: @amWhy This isn't really a link only answer. The actual number is here, not just a link to the engine that did the computation. It is potentially useful even if Wolfram Alpha goes away.

Comment: There is indeed no link.

Answer (score 1):

By the Stirling approximation, the first missing term in the infinite summation would be

$$\frac{30^{49}}{49!}\approx\frac{(30e)^{49}}{\sqrt{98\pi}\,49^{49}}\approx3940716560.$$

This is to be compared to the infinite sum, $e^{30}\approx10686474581524$.

As the tail of the summation does not exceed $e$ times the first omitted term, the approximation as $e^{30}$ yields a relative error not exceeding $10^{-3}$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer will have a massive denominator; it's basically just a complicated rational number. In my opinion, you're better off saying the answer is roughly $e^{30}$. The difference will be tiny. Indeed, the ratio test tells us that the partial sums of $\exp$ converge faster than geometrically beyond the $x$th partial sum.

Comment: "The difference will be tiny": how can one show it ? Until $k=30$, the factorial "lags behind".